# How do I get all string values, not Keys, from a JSON using RegEx?

Tags: json, regex

This is the regex I have so far but it is selecting Keys. I only want to select all occurrences of values: https://regex101.com/r/fA5cP9/1

```
{
    "contact": {
        "name": "John Doe",
        "label": "Web Developer",
        "email": "email@example.com",
        "phone": "(123) 123-1234",
        "website": "www.example.com",
        "profiles": [{
            "network": "LinkedIn",
            "url": "www.linkedin.com"
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to solve this with a regex?

Comment: Is there a better way? I need to make a single array of all values?

Comment: Also, what are you actually trying to achieve after you have a list of all the values? The purpose of JSON is already to organize data in a logical structure. Why would you try to extract the already organized values in a list?

Comment: Use a JSON parser. It'll be *much* easier to process and use the data.

Comment: Add the colon with optional space: `\: *"(.*?)\"`

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles You forgot the whitespace.

Comment: I want to be able to replace all the all of the JSON values with lorem ipsum because I want to pull through dummy text through a Resume Design html view.

Comment: @user1869257 _But why?_ You already have “John Doe” etc. Isn’t that already dummy text? Your requirement is a bit weird.

Comment: I'll be honest, it is a dumb school assignment. It doesn't seem practical to me either. Here are the requirements:

1. var resume = //contents of your resume.json

2. var greekedResume =  //programmatically convert all the string values to lorem ipsum, not the keys.

You'll have 2 json variables that are identical except for the values. They will both have the same keys.

Comment: The assignment sounds more like you should _change_ the JSON, not extract all the value strings from it… and it really doesn’t sound like you should use regex.

Comment: I thought I could extract all of the values then for loop through them with a string replace of an array of lorem ipsum words. How would you recommend I replace all of the JSON values with lorem ipsum?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114050/discussion-between-user1869257-and-xufox).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this is not exactly a real world problem to solve, it’s probably easiest to stick to the RegEx approach.

Your RegEx is almost correct, you just forgot one thing: the sole thing that distinguishes keys from values is the colon between the two. Each value is *preceded* by a colon, so you have to change the RegEx to `\:\s?\"(.*?)\"`. The `\s?` makes sure it works, even if there’s a space after the colon.

Now you need to stringify the JSON, make the replacements and then re-parse it:

```
var resume = {
    "contact": {
        "name": "John Doe",
        "label": "Web Developer",
        "email": "email@example.com",
        "phone": "(123) 123-1234",
        "website": "www.example.com",
        "profiles": [{
            "network": "LinkedIn",
            "url": "www.linkedin.com"
        }]
    }
};

var greekedResume = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(resume)
    .replace(/:\s?\"(.*?)\"/g, ":\"Lorem ipsum\""));
```